# mongodb sharding on ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i have a collection with an attribute employee_uuid which is a objectID. Can this attribute be a sharding key?

Is there a restriction that only datatypes other than objectID can be a shard key?

Comment: Study https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=mongodb+choose+shard+key&ia=web

Answer (score 0):

No restriction on that. Make sure you have high cardinality, and non-monotonically increasing shard key. Think carefully what you shard on!

There are two ways to shard:

1. Range based sharding
2. Hashed sharding

Depending on your queries, you can choose which one works for you.

Comment: how about employee_id with hashed index ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can share self assigned attributes no matter the datatype.
If you really want to use a non shareable one, you probably have to access the _id or define it inside your Schema (& application logic ofc).